# graph convolution network

Tags: neural-networks, graphical-model, geometry, graph-neural-network

I am trying to understand papers and lectures on graph convolution networks but whenever I open some paper, I get lost on the very first page. I started with some videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvmjbXZyoP0&t=405s) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrhBZUtgG4E) and papers like [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08097.pdf) but I always get lost. Is there any good starting point to under this technique? Will reading about graph theory help me understand this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably useful to have a basic understanding of the fourier transform, the graph laplacian, and at least some introductory knowledge about spectral analysis (the study of the eigenvalues of the graph laplacian). You don't really need to know any graph theory beyond the basics. Then I would start with [Convolutional Neural Networks on Graphs
with Fast Localized Spectral Filtering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09375.pdf), as it's one of the first papers on graph convolutions and explains pretty clearly what's going on

This may be personal taste, but I tend to stay away from survey papers when trying to understand a new topic, because they often try to reformulate and present every previous work into a single unified framework -- which rarely ends well and results in some pretty obtuse notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. Do you recommend any good sources for spectral analysis and graph Laplacian?